# oAuth2 redirect URI to AngularJS app with a hash in the URI

Tags: angularjs, http, redirect

I have an oAuth2 service where I want to pass the redirect_uri param as a url to somewhere in my AngularJS application - e.g. `http://localhost:8080/#/twitter/list` but my oAuth2 provider doesn't recognise URLs with hash symbols in them. I've tried changing the url to be `http://localhost:8080/%23/twitter/list` but Angular doesn't seem to recognise the path and I get the following error in my browser:

```
Cannot GET /%23/twitter/list
```

How can I get a redirect back to my AngularJS app to work?

Comment: Any solutions yet ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use a hashtag at all. In modern browsers (all except old IE), which supports HTML 5, you can skip that hashtag. This is not enabled by default, but you can change it in your app.

Under the section in your app with routes config, you need to inject additional $locationProvider which then should be used for that. Please take a look on example below with *ui-router* (same applicable to *ng-router*) :

```
angular.module('app').config(function( $stateProvider, 
    $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider ){
    //Routes
    //...
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

With the similar setup, you don't need to use a hashtag anywhere in your app. It means original issue will be fixed